# Mosquitto Service issue on Windows

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

After I made changes to the mosquitto.conf file for adding TLS support, I restarted the Mosquitto Broker service but its not starting. The error says the Mosquitto Service started on Local computer and then stopped -

```
# MQTT over TLS
listener 8883
cafile C:Program Files (x86)mosquittocertificatesca.crt
certfile C:Program Files (x86)mosquittocertificatesserver.crt
keyfile C:Program Files (x86)mosquittocertificatesserver.key
```

This error also occurs when I made changes to the mosquitto.conf file-

```
listener 9001 0.0.0.0
protocol websockets
```

I am using a Windows 10 machine. Did anyone face this problem?

Comment: The path to certificate files is wrong, it's missing the \ separators and should probably be wrapped in " marks as it has spaces in it.

Comment: Then why is the second code too not working when I am setting the listener only and no certificate paths?

Comment: Not sure without seeing the output from mosquitto when you start it. Rather than using the service, try starting it on the command line with the `-c` option to point to the conf file so you can see the errors. Update the question with this output.

Comment: Actually now I think about it, the default shipped version of mosquitto for windows does NOT have websocket support enabled. You have to build it from source to enable it.

Comment: Sure will do. I am away from my computer but will run this and update. Thanks!

Comment: So, the 1.4.14 version (latest) also does not have websocket support?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153684/discussion-between-user1930106-and-hardillb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As worked through in the comments.

The paths to the certificates need to have the correct path separators '\' included and as they contain spaces should be wrapped in quotes. e.g.

```
# MQTT over TLS
listener 8883
cafile "C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\certificates\ca.crt"
certfile "C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\certificates\server.crt"
keyfile "C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\certificates\server.key"
```

Also the pre-built version of mosquitto for Windows does not include websocket support. If you need websocket support you will have to built it from the source yourself and build and include the libwebsocket dependency.

Comment: I will surely try this. 
Websocket support you will have to built it from the source - can you refer to some link

Comment: Instructions for building with websockets support: https://github.com/bapowell/bapowell.github.io/wiki/Mosquitto-Build-Notes-(Windows-Visual-Studio)-Sept-14-2018

Comment: My understanding is that since 1.5.1 (https://mosquitto.org/blog/2018/08/version-151-released/)  mosquitto for Windows has included web socket support.