# Why MQTT Over Websocket with ssl not working

Tags: ssl, mqtt

Created certificate by referring: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/#comment-1363 , 
and applied below setting in mosquitto config file:

```
listener 8883
protocol websockets 
cafile C:\Program Files(x86)\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt 
certfile C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\certs\server.crt 
keyfile C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\certs\server.key
```

and trying to publish message from below command:

```
mosquitto_pub -h mdcc -p 8883  -m "1" -t TrainA-Extruder/Bompos -d --cafile C:\Program~Files~(x86)\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt --cert C:\Program~Files~(x86)\mosquitto\certs\srvserver.crt --key C:\Program~Files~(x86)\mosquitto\certs\server.key --insecure
```

[image: Error]

getting error:problem setting TLS Option
Tried another command and getting error :

[image: Error]

cannot start in daemon mode in windows

Comment: Do not post images of log output, post the actual text so it can be searched

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mosquitto Service issue on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049035/mosquitto-service-issue-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

`mosquitto_pub` and `mosquitto_sub` do not support MQTT over Websockets. You can not use them to test mosquitto websocket listeners.

The second error (unable to start because the port is already in use) is most likely because mosquitto is already running as a Windows service. If you want to test changes to your `mosquitto.conf` file you will need to stop the service first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried with mqtt protocol also, and getting same error.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have restarted the mosquitto service after you changed the config file?

Comment: Yes , after adding new item in config file I'm restarting the broker from service.

Comment: And websocket is perfectly working from normal (Without SSL) call from javascript client